# Quicksort: algorithm works only with specific pivot

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I wrote this implementation of the quicksort algorithm.
In theory the quicksort should work using any pivot but my code is not able to correctly sort the array.

If I use l as pivot the algorithm works but I'm not able to understand why it doesn't work using h. Any idea?

```
public ArrayList<Integer> sort(ArrayList<Integer> array, int l, int h){
    if ((h - l) > 0){
        int splitPoint = partition(array, l, h);
        sort(array, l, splitPoint);
        sort(array, splitPoint +1, h);
    }
    return array;
}

public int partition(ArrayList<Integer> array, int l, int h) {
    int p = h; //with int p = l; the algorithm works
    Integer pivot = array.get(p);

    while(l<h) {
        for (; h>l && array.get(h).compareTo(pivot) >= 0; h--);
        for (; l<h && array.get(l).compareTo(pivot) < 0; l++);

        swap(array, l, h);
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: We can not tell you what is wrong with an implementation that you have not shown us.  You must show us both the working and non working versions, before we can tell you for sure what you did wrong.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I tried to rephrase my question and I've put the wrong code

Answer (score 0):

You can use your existing algorithm.

If you want to choose another pivot, swap it to the first position in `partition`.

Comment: My question was a bit different:is it possible to write an implementation of the quicksort algorithm that works using any element as pivot?

Comment: Ok, but in theory the quicksort should work with any pivot. With your method I'll be back at my algorithm. Why I cannot use as pivot the last one? I'm trying to understand which problem my algorithm has. I'm writing this only as exercise so I'ld like to write the best implementation possible

Comment: I've tried also with other implementations found on internet but also with those if I change the pivot the algorithm doesn't work anymore and I don't understand why...

Comment: "With your method I'll be back at my algorithm." - I don't understand what the problem is. "Why I cannot use as pivot the last one?" - you can. No idea what you're doing, please post code how you changed `partition`.

Comment: With this code if I use int p = h; as pivot the algorithm doesn't work anymore and I was trying to understand why